# how to run a command on different terminal using fork() and execlp()

Tags: c

I had written a program using NCURSES in which i am displaying a menu on one terminal and want to use fork() and execlp() in the same program but whatever command i am running using fork() and execlp() had to be executed on a different terminal or in the back ground.How that can be done.I am simply using

```
if(fork())
wait(0);
else
execlp("ls","ls",(char *)NULL);
```

within a conditional statement which is displaying a message on the main terminal and will be executing the command inside execlp in the background

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to start a new terminal, and hand it the command to run.

If you look at the command line parameters of e.g. [gnome-terminal](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/gnome_terminal) you can figure out how to format the command line.

Comment: actually what is happening in my program all the simple programs are running on the same terminal and are over lapping my GUI but every net based command like local host,telnet 0 5000 are not even working on the same terminal.well right now i just want to run command to check my functionality of program.